# how to cast to object in razor syntax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

```
@using System.Data
@model DataTable

@foreach (var row in Model.Rows)
{
   @row[]  // how do you cast this to a object?
}
```

How do you cast @row to an object in Razor syntax?

Comment: Shouldn't you just be able to use it as `row`, without the '@' and the brackets?

Answer (score 8):

You can just write common C# code:

```
@foreach (YourType row in Model.Rows)
{
     ...
}
```

or

```
@foreach (var row in Model.Rows)
{
    YourType casted = (YourType)row;
    ...
}
```

or if you're not sure if it's castable:

```
@foreach (var row in Model.Rows)
{
    YourType casted = row as YourType;

    if (casted != null)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I happened upon this problem today. The solution I used was using parenthesis:

```
@((YourType) row)
```